# Square bracket notation in equation

Tags: notation

I'm attempting to understand a paper[[1](http://visgraph.cse.ust.hk/projects/skeleton/)] on contracting geometry for computer graphics. I have an undergraduate Physics degrees to give some indication of my experience, though that was 6 years ago now.

I'm stumbling on a basic part as I'm unfamiliar with the notation:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{W}_L\mathbf{L} \\
\mathbf{W}_H
\end{bmatrix}\mathbf{V}' = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
\mathbf{W}_H\mathbf{V}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Were to blindly guess I'd suggest it was shorthand for specifying:

$$
\mathbf{W}_L\mathbf{L}\mathbf{V}' = 0
$$
and
$$
\mathbf{W}_H\mathbf{V}' = \mathbf{W}_H\mathbf{V}
$$

But then I'm confused by the relevance of the second equation in the context.

I don't know if I've provided enough information. Happy to provide more if desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those square brackets are the notation for matrices. See the wikipedia article about [mathematics matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)).

If you're doing computer graphics work, you should at least know *some* Linear Algebra, you can view a few lectures here :
http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/.

Comment: Thanks, I think I was confused by W, L & V all being matrices as well.  So they're matrices of matrices?

Comment: Sure are, they're simply block matrices. That is, the matrices are written in terms of smaller matrices.

Comment: Great thanks, apparently I've not encountered block matrices before. Thanks for the link too, seems like it is time to address a gap in my knowledge.

Comment: No problem. Since you've been through Physics, may I suggest a textbook that may be suitable, perhaps "Linear Algebra Done Right" by Axler, see http://amzn.com/0387982582 . Something fun to keep around your desk, if nothing else.